# Calculate position with increasing acceleration.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

So if calculating the change in an object's position (with a constant acceleration) is done with this equation:

$o = vt + (\frac12)a t^2$

$o$ is offset from original position
$v$ is starting velocity
$t$ is time
$a$ is acceleration

How would I calculate change in position if **acceleration** is changing (at a fixed rate).

Like thus?

$o = vt + (\frac12)a t^2 + (\frac12)i t^{2^2}$
or
$o = vt + (\frac12)a t^2 + (\frac12)i t^3$

$i$ is increase rate of acceleration

Comment: Do you know how the equation of motion with constant acceleration is derived?

Comment: your question is quite hard to understand, can you please edit

Comment: If acceleration is changing at a constant rate, then we have $x'''(t) = k$. Now integrate three times to get $x(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

From the definition of acceleration $a$ and velocity $v$ you know that 
$$
a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}
$$
where $x$ is the position (the space). So, if $a=it$ you have to solve the equation:
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= it
$$

can you do this?

---

If you don't know the calculus (derivatives and integrals) it is difficult to find the equation of motion for non constant acceleration.

In your case, if $a=it$ and $i$ is a constant, we can find the velocity $v(t)$ in a way analogous to that used in the uniformly accelerated motion for to find the position $x(t)$ from the velocity $v=at$, and this gives: $v(t)=\frac{1}{2}it^2+v_0$.

But now we have to find the position $x(t)$ and this cannot be done in a simple way without the use of calculus.

The idea is that we start from:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=v(t)=\frac{1}{2}it^2+v_0
$$
Where $dx$ is the little (infinitesimal) change of position for an infinitesimal time interval $dt$, so that the infintesimal change of position $dx$ is:
$$
dx=\left(\frac{1}{2}it^2+v_0 \right)dt
$$
than we sum up all this infinitesimal displacements to find the position at time $t$. This intuition can be defined rigorously and captured in the notion of integral.

The final result , in your case, is the equation of motion:
$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{6}it^3+v_0t+s_0
$$

Comment: What is $d$? . .

Comment: $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is the derivative of the velocity. Do you know derivatives?

Comment: Um, no, I guess not.

Comment: I've added something to my answer. But you need some more knowledge on mathematics to solve this problem by yourself.